# Get last exe file Execution Date (or Time) in Windows using .NET or VB6

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, file, vb6

Basically, I wouldn't find this anywhere. All I really need is date last executed, or even date last shutdown (that is, exe ended execution). I don't even need a catalog of all runs/shutdowns, just the last one.

I'm sure they must keep it somewhere. Reason being, in control panel (Win Vista) when you go to "programs & features" you have the option to sort the programs by how often they are used (which is run/executed) since this will not be based on last accessed time. Then, in their description, they quote usage frequency with terms such as "rarely", "sometimes", "often", "regularly" etc...

Now in Win7, if you right click on the columns & select "more..." from the installed programs listing control, you'll see a "Last Used On" option! This implies that last used date is at least kept somewhere in Win7.

Any ideas anyone?

*Update: About LastAccess DateTime:* LastAccess is too unreliable it seems (correct me if i'm wrong) it keeps on changing as soon as something (such as windows) accesses it. Maybe i should ask, does windows mess this field up by accessing the file to read info out of it (such as file size/dates etc) especially when browsing folders or does windows access files secretly to prevent contaminating the last access dates?

Comment: in Windows Vista and above, Last Access Time is turned off by default and not updated, this is only altered on creation, so windows should not be altering thoughs dates, unless it's turned on manually

Comment: Explorer keeps track of when shortcuts to certain executables are used (to keep the list of frequently accessed programs) which MAY be exposed by the `IShellLink` interfaces. If not, I expect it's not public.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

This is apparently different for MSI installations.

Information got from this thread (last post):

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/55552-45-remove-program-date

> For an MSI installation Windows Installer maintains a usage count in its own registry   > >based on Product and Feature, which can be found for example under
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\\Usage
>
> This is maintained by the Windows Installer API.
>
> MsiUseFeature() increments the usage counter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370502(VS.85).aspx)
>   MsiGetFeatureUsage() gets the Last Used Date and the Use Count
>
> The usage counter is also incremented when launching an application via an advertised shortcut or when using one of the MsiProvide*() functions.

**UPDATE**

Check out this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx

It seems like those values aren't stored anywhere, but more like an assumtion. So you might aswell use the `File.GetLastAccessTime` to get this.

You could also use a `FileSystemWatcher` and `Process`. Then set a flag when the `FileSystemWatcher` sees a change and the exe is started.

Comment: check out my update. Also, how reliable do you think LastAccess DateTime is? How often is it contaminated by windows processes accessing it?

Comment: Well, I'm using Win7 but I'd need my solution to work on WinXP & above, or at least WinVista & above (or, as many OS's as possible). By access, I'm not sure I knew entirely what it is defined to be. Is right-click and checking its properties considered an Access?

Comment: Also, i read the msdn blog article, that is just amazing - it blew me the hell away, wow! all they'd have to do is popup a msg for apps installing after the OS first beta launch date to ensure all fields are inserted, and you watch all dev's altering the code to get rid of that msgbox asking for more details during installation lol.

Comment: No, right-click and checking is not a part of altering the access time. As I see it then the best way and most accurate would be to make a FileSystemWatcher to check for the access and if the process is running, flag it and save the DateTime and then unflag it when the process isn't running anymore.

Comment: Those Installer registry entries aren't what you seem to think they are.  See https://installpac.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/packed-guids-darwin-descriptors-and-windows-installer-reference-counting/